# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'IntlChar' not found

Tags: php, json

I am working with a huge 40GB json file and I am using JSON pull parser for PHP 7 to extract data from the huge file. Here is [my dummy json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsdTN5eHJoZHZMeG8/view?usp=sharing).

I want to extract data from attribute "entityStatusDescription" in form of a table as thus:

```
 `ENTITYSTATUSDESCRIPTION`
      `removed`
     `registered`
      `removed`
      `removed`
    `registered`
      `removed`
```

I am able to extract data from other attributes but when extracting data from attribute `entityStatusDescription`, there are only few rows that were extracted and then, there is an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'IntlChar' not found in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Lexer.php:285 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Lexer.php(161):
>   pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Lexer->evaluateEscapedUnicodeSequence() #1
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Lexer.php(191):
>   pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Lexer->evaluateEscapeSequence() #2
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Lexer.php(101):
>   pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Lexer->evaluateDoubleQuotedString() #3
>   [internal function]: pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Lexer->getIterator() #4
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Parser.php(180):
>   IteratorIterator->next() #5
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Parser.php(152):
>   pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Parser->parsePair() #6
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Parser.php(205):
>   pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Parser->parseObject() #7
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Parser.php(123):
>   pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Parser->parseValue in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Lexer.php on line
>   285

I will be glad for help. Here is my code:

```
 <?php
     require_once "E:/xampp/htdocs/vendor/autoload.php";    
     use \pcrov\JsonReader\JsonReader;
     ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
     $reader = new JsonReader();
     $reader->open("jsonfile.json");    
     $fo = fopen("csvfile.csv", "w" );
     fputs($fo, "companyStatus".PHP_EOL);
     while($reader->read()) {


         if ($reader->read("entityStatusDescription")){
             $entityStatusDescription = $reader->value();
         }  
         fputs($fo,  $entityStatusDescription.PHP_EOL);

  }
  $reader->close();
```

Comment: How are you installing the `JsonReader`? According to its [`composer.json`](https://github.com/pcrov/JsonReader/blob/master/composer.json#L21) file, it requires the `ext-intl` extension. You shouldn't have been able to install it without that extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get this error message, you need to install the Intl extension.

Please refer to the PHP manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

Comment: Thanks. I took the following steps bearing in mind that I used windows: (1) back up my htdocs folder in xampp. (2) uninstall xampp, (3) reinstall xampp, (4) open the php.ini file in xampp\php directory, and simply uncomment the extension "extension=php_intl.dll" by removing the semi-colon preceding it, (5) download and run "Composer-Setup.exe", (6) install the streaming pull parser known as "pcrov/jsonreader". This is done by pasting "composer require pcrov/jsonreader" on the command prompt, in the directory you want it to be (e.g. \xampp\htdocs). Thereafter, I do not have the error message.

Comment: Uncommenting the extension in your php.ini was the crucial step then.